# Add force relative to angle of game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create lunar lander in Unity2D but am having issues with adding thrust in a certain direction, mainly the direction the rocket is facing. Currently, it will always vertical even if the ship is at a 90 degree angle.

```
    public float thrust;
private Rigidbody2D rocket;
public int rotationSpeed;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rocket = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
    {
        if (rocket.transform.rotation.z < 90 && rocket.transform.rotation.z > -90)
        {
            Debug.Log(rocket.transform.rotation.z);
            float angle = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            if (angle > 0)
            {
                rocket.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            }
            else
            {
                rocket.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            }
        }
    }

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
    {

        Debug.Log(rocket.transform.rotation.z);
        float angle = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        if (angle > 0)
        {
            rocket.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * 10);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
`rocket.AddForce(Vector3.up*10, ForceMode.Impulse);`
```

instead

Comment: Nope, if i rotate the ship 90 degrees, it will still go directly vertical

Comment: 2d or 3d? the reason its still going up is because your using it parents transform, not the transform of the object that actually rotates